# Displaying C++ source code with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, listings

I’m trying to have some C++ source code displayed in a TikZ environment (I'm using TikZ to have several copies of the same text on a single page, so that when it is printed I can cut the sheet into identical parts and save paper).

The code below is not working and I don’t really understand why. Can anyone help me fix it ? Perhaps I should not use the listing package ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
language=C,
basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\tiny,
frame=tb,
columns=fullflexible,
showstringspaces=false
}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
  \noindent   \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
\foreach \x in {0,10.5,21}
  {
    \draw (\x ,0) -- (\x ,29.65);
  };
\foreach \y in {0,7.41,14.83,22.24,29.65}
  {
    \draw (0, \y) -- (21, \y);
  };

 \foreach \x in {0,10.5}
  {
 \foreach \y in {0,7.41,14.83,22.24}
  {  
\draw(0.5+\x,3.75+\y) node [right,text width=9.5cm] {
{\bf  BTS SIO 1\`ere ann\'ee}\ \newline
{\bf  Correction pour le tri de trois nombres}\ \ 

\begin{lstlisting}
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // insert code here...
    int a,b,c,ancien;
    cout << "Entrez le premier nombre\n";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Entrez le second nombre\n";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Entrez le troisième nombre\n";
    cin >> c;
    if (b<a) {
        ancien=a;
        a=b;
        b=ancien;
    }
    if (c<b) {
        ancien=b;
        b=c;
        c=ancien;
    }
    if (b<a) {
        ancien=a;
        a=b;
        b=ancien;
    }
    cout << "Voici les nombres dans l'ordre croissant : \n" << a << "," << b << "," << c << "\n";
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlsiting}


};
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  The `listings` package may very well be causing the issue here, but I would reconsider your basic approach.  There are packages to shrink pages like this.

Comment: not that it would change anything but `\end{lstlsiting}` has a typo and should be `\end{lstlisting}`. In case people copy paste your code.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 12):

Without PSTricks or TikZ. Just use `pdfpages`.

### Step 1

Prepare the C++ source code, save it as `source-code.cpp`, for example, in the same directory in which your LaTeX input file will be saved. `source-code.cpp` is given as follows.

```cpp
// source-code.cpp

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // insert code here...
    int a,b,c,ancien;
    cout << "Entrez le premier nombre\n";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Entrez le second nombre\n";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Entrez le troisième nombre\n";
    cin >> c;
    if (b<a) {
        ancien=a;
        a=b;
        b=ancien;
    }
    if (c<b) {
        ancien=b;
        b=c;
        c=ancien;
    }
    if (b<a) {
        ancien=a;
        a=b;
        b=ancien;
    }
    cout << "Voici les nombres dans l'ordre croissant : \n" << a << "," << b << "," << c << "\n";
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // insert code here...
    int a,b,c,ancien;
    cout << "Entrez le premier nombre\n";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Entrez le second nombre\n";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Entrez le troisième nombre\n";
    cin >> c;
    if (b<a) {
        ancien=a;
        a=b;
        b=ancien;
    }
    if (c<b) {
        ancien=b;
        b=c;
        c=ancien;
    }
    if (b<a) {
        ancien=a;
        a=b;
        b=ancien;
    }
    cout << "Voici les nombres dans l'ordre croissant : \n" << a << "," << b << "," << c << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

### Step 2

Create an auxiliary LaTeX input file named `auxiliary.tex` to convert your `source-code.cpp` to a PDF version with syntax highlighting. `auxiliary.tex` should be saved in the same directory in which the `source-code.cpp` exists.

```
% auxiliary.tex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=15mm]{geometry}


% this part is used to allow your readers to copy the code from a PDF viewer but without copying the line numbers.
\usepackage{accsupp}
\newcommand*{\noaccsupp}[1]{\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}#1\EndAccSupp{}}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{shared}
{
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=1em,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{red}\noaccsupp,
    frame=single,
    framesep=\fboxsep,
    framerule=\fboxrule,
    rulecolor=\color{red},
    xleftmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax,
    xrightmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax,
    breaklines=true,
    tabsize=2,
    columns=flexible,
}


\lstdefinestyle{cpp}
{
    style=shared,
    language={[ANSI]C++},
    alsolanguage={Python},
    basicstyle=\small\tt,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.13,0.54,0.13},
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!10},
    morekeywords={
        Console,
        WriteLine,
        int,
  },
}

%\lstnewenvironment{cpp}
%{\lstset{style=cpp}}
%{}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[style=cpp]{source-code.cpp}
\end{document}
```

### Step 3

Compile `auxiliary.tex` with PDFLaTeX compiler. You can do this from within the text editor you use but for the sake of generality, do it via a console window. Change the current directory to the directory in which both `source-code.cpp` and `auxiliary.tex` exist. Invoke

```
pdflatex auxiliary
```

Now you will have `auxiliary.pdf` containing your C++ code with syntax highlighting.

### Step 4

Create the following input file and save it as `main.tex` in the same directory in which the two other files mentioned above exists.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[nup=2x2,pages=-,duplicatepages=4,frame=true]{master.pdf}
\end{document}
```

### Step 5

It is the final step. Compile the `main.tex` via the console window as follows.

```
pdflatex main
```

And you will get the following output without animation effect for sure.

[image]

Comment: @user40960: If you like it, please accept it by clicking the check mark button below the down vote button, which in turn below the score label. Optionally you may vote it up once.

Comment: When I copy-pasted your suggestion into my tex file, I got the following error message : Package pdfpages Error : Cannot find file master.pdf

Comment: Really? Where and when ? I have a very low rep count, so perhaps I cannot participate in chat rooms.

Comment: Perhaps a few hints will suffice ? I am dumb, but not that dumb ... By the way, I fixed the error above by compiling the pdf.tex file separately, but now I get another error message : Package keyval error : duplicatepackages undefined.

Comment: Ok, please add a little comment when you’re finished updating it.

Comment: @DonutEKnot Wait, wait : it’s still not working. Everything works fine up to Step 4. But when I try to compile main.tex, I get exactly the same error message as before : Package keyval error : duplicatepackages undefined.

Comment: @DonutEKnot Yes, I’ve put all the file in the same directory. I visualize auxiliary.pdf fine.

Comment: @DonutEKnot Mine is much older indeed : 2012/04/03. How should I update ? (I’m using TeXShop).

Comment: I’ll try, but predictably there’ll be soon another post here about “Trouble when updating to TeX Live 2013”.

Comment: @DonutEKnot I updated successfully to TeX Live 2013 and now I have some output, but unfortunately I’m not satsified yet : in your proposal (unlike jfbu's answer) you left out the non-C++ part (consisting of the two lines {\bfseries  BTS SIO 1\`ere ann\'ee}\newline  {\bfseries  Correction pour le tri de trois nombres}\ \ ). When I re-inserted it, the PDF becam two-paged ; I have no problem with that, but the thing is, much of the code is repeated between page 1 and page 2 - a terrible waste of space.

Answer (score 5):

There were quite a few issues with your code; among them some extra or missing braces and the fact that you can't fit all of that material as many times on one A4 page without overlapping, some problems with accented characters in the source code for listings, and a missing `linewidth` option to pass to `listings`. But, bottomline is that you can put the `listings` stuff inside a Box, and then use that box in your `tikz picture` (as listings obviously changes catcodes, it is no surprise that you can't use it in an environment like `tikz picture` which parses its contents).

*edit:* you should **not** end your `\foreach` loops with a `;`!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
language=C,
basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\tiny,
frame=tb,
columns=fullflexible,
showstringspaces=false,
extendedchars,%
literate={è}{{\`e}}1,%
linewidth=9.5cm,%
% inputencoding=utf8, % does not seem to work
}

\newbox\CodeBox

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setbox\CodeBox \vbox{\hsize=10cm {% doubled braces for color safety
\begin{lstlisting}
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // insert code here...
    int a,b,c,ancien;
    cout << "Entrez le premier nombre\n";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Entrez le second nombre\n";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Entrez le troisième nombre\n";
    cin >> c;
    if (b<a) {
        ancien=a;
        a=b;
        b=ancien;
    }
    if (c<b) {
        ancien=b;
        b=c;
        c=ancien;
    }
    if (b<a) {
        ancien=a;
        a=b;
        b=ancien;
    }
    cout << "Voici les nombres dans l'ordre croissant : \n" 
         << a << "," << b << "," << c << "\n";
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
}}

  \noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
\foreach \x in {0,10.5,20.95} 
  {
    \draw (\x ,0) -- (\x ,29.65);
  }% no ; here!
%\foreach \y in {0,7.41,14.83,22.24,29.65}
\foreach \y in {0,14.83,29.65}
  {
    \draw (0, \y) -- (20.95, \y);
  }% no ; here!

 \foreach \x in {0,10.5}
%  {\foreach \y in {0,7.41,14.83,22.24}
  {\foreach \y in {0,14.83}
  {\draw(0.5+\x,\y) node [above right,text width=10cm] 
    {{\bfseries  BTS SIO 1\`ere ann\'ee}\newline
     {\bfseries  Correction pour le tri de trois nombres}\ \ 

     \usebox\CodeBox
    };
  }% end of \y loop
}% end of \x loop

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: listings]

Comment: @user40960 of course you can upvote and accept [Marienplatz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19356/marienplatz)'s answer, everybody will be happy as he gives up his reps in bounties distributed to others. Nevertheless, if you like this answer, you are free to upvote and accept it too!

Comment: My question is, how about the case in which the code spans more than one physical page? :-)

Comment: @Marienplatz then I am doomed :(

Comment: as added in a comment to the OP's original code, drawing a vertical rule at horizontal position `\x=21cm` is uneffective. One should use `20.95cm` or a more sophisticated `21cm minus the width of the rule`. In the `20.95cm` case, the horizontal rules then should also preferably not go all the way to `21cm`. Anyhow, I don't have access to printing machines which do not have some printer margins, hence these things will be cut out, and possibly the only relevant rules to be drawn in such situations are the ones going through the center of the page.

Comment: (changes mentioned in comments incorporated in answer, image not updated)

Comment: @jfbu I copy-pasted your code, the PDF output is fine but unfortunately the borders will be cut out as you say, so that’s not really usable for me. Thanks for the code corrections!

Comment: @user40960 yes, [ex-Marienplatz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19356/donut-e-knot)'s code with `pdfpages` is definitely the way to go; for shorter code excerpts the box method is simple and sometimes suffices.